# I am currently experiencing an AAPT error in Android Studio. Studio is failing to find an XML resource for the given value

Tags: android, xml

1. No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/TextView.Output').

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Any advice on how to incorporate this?

Comment: Where are you referencing `@style/TextView.Output`?

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have any style in your `styles.xml` with the name "TextView.Output".**

You can do One of the following Methods.

Create a new style with the name `TextView.Output`

Or

Wherever you are using `TextView.Output`, replace it to `AppTheme`